# SQL "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value" error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

```
create table ApplicationTracker_dup1
select transactionid,
       count(case when attribute = 'Secci_Page_Arrival_Time' and value is not null then transactionid end)as secci_visits,
       count(case when attribute = 'esign_arrival_time' and value is not null then transactionid end)as esig_visits 
from ApplicationTracker_dup 
where create_dtm < '2013-08-13' 
group by 1;
```

when I run this code, I encounter

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'E031CF1DE8F7'"

and table is not being created. Can some one help me here?

Comment: This warning happens also while just running the SELECT (without table create), it is a reported bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43437

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you didn't post `ApplicationTracker_dup` table definition script so I propose to try use cast either with `attribute` columns in select clause or with `create_dtm` column like this:

```
cast(attribute as char)
```

or

```
cast(create_dtm as char)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use int or NULL in **count** func, not char and other types
So, this code should work without warnings:

```
create table ApplicationTracker_dup1
select transactionid,
       count(if(attribute = 'Secci_Page_Arrival_Time' and value is not null,1,NULL)) as secci_visits,
       count(if(attribute = 'esign_arrival_time' and value is not null,1,NULL)) as esig_visits 
from ApplicationTracker_dup 
where create_dtm < '2013-08-13' 
group by 1;
```